# Java-dynamic-binding-problem-understanding

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, dynamic-binding

So, I have this problem (which I am guessing has something to do with dynamic binding) that I can not wrap my head around.

```
class A {
    public int m(A p) {
        return 12;
    }

    public int n(A p) {
        return 38;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public int m(B p) {
        return 3;
    }

    public int n(A p) {
        return 7;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public int m(A p) {
        return 38;
    }
    public int n(A p) {
        return 4;
    }
}
class D extends A {
    public int m(A p) {
        return 1;
    }

    public int n(D p) {
        return 2;
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        A x = new C();
        A y = new D();
        D z = new D();
        System.out.println(x.m(z) + y.n(z)); //*
    }
}
```

The commented line is where I get stuck. Why the result is 76? what does it depend on, because I have been searching all over the internet and I wasn't able to find an example for it. if you can come up with little explanations I would very much appreciate.

Comment: What result do you expect? Why not add some print statements so you can see which methods are being called, or step through the code with the debugger. Then explain *exactly* what part of the behaviour you see you think is wrong.

Comment: Which _method_ is used is determined at compile-time. This is based off the _compile-time_ types of the references involved. Which _implementation_ is used is determined at run-time. This is based off the actual object's type at _run-time_. For instance, the compile-time type of `x` is `A`, but at run-time it is assigned an object of type `C`. Also, a method that has the same name as another method but a different number or type of parameters _overloads_ that other method, it does not _override_ it (e.g., `D::n(D)` does not override `A::n(A)`, it overloads it).

Comment: Note: Always add the `@Override` annotation to methods you intend to override a method from a superclass or interface. The compiler will then verify for you if that method actually overrides anything, emitting an error if it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns 76, because both parts of sum returned 38:

`x.m(z)` this part means, try to find method `m` within class `A` (because `x` is `A`) which can accept `D`, **there is no such method in `A`**, but there is `m` which accepts `A`, as soon as `D` extends from `A` - this method is used, so we're calling method `A.m(A)`, but this method is overridden in `C`, so overridden method is actually executed, ie `C.m(A)`

`y.n(z)` this part follows the same logic and tries to call `A.n(A)`, but class `D` does not override method `n` - `public int n(D p)` is not override for `A.n(A)`, so non overridden method from `A` is executed

I suggest you to always use `@Override` annotation to allow compiler to validate what methods are actually overridden and what not, here is annotated version which is easier to follow:

```
class A {
    public int m(A p) {return 12;}
    public int n(A p) {return 38;}
}
class B extends A {
    public int m(B p) {return 3;}
    @Override
    public int n(A p) {return 7;}
}
class C extends A {
    @Override
    public int m(A p) {return 38;}
    @Override
    public int n(A p) {return 4;}
}
class D extends A {
    @Override
    public int m(A p) {return 1;}
    public int n(D p) {return 2;}
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        A x = new C();
        A y = new D();
        D z = new D();
        System.out.println(x.m(z) + y.n(z)); //*
    }
}
```

to allow compiler to find `n(D)` method you must cast y to `D`, like `((D)y).n(z)` or use derived type in declaration `D y = new D();`

Comment: I almost got it, but if x is A, and it can accept D, but there is no method for m(D p) anywhere, why are we going to the overriden m(A p) method in C? why the result for x.m(z) isn't 12 from the base class A? is it because x is an instance of the C class? or is there another explanation? sorry I am a total begginer, I just want to understand

Comment: `why are we going to the overriden m(A p) method in C` because this is how inheritance works, we can call method which accepts base class with derived one, `why the result for x.m(z) isn't 12` because C overrides this method

Comment: yeah, but following that logic doesn't mean that n(A p) methods in B and C are overriding n(A p) method in A? so that means y.n(z) should return 7 or 4

Comment: @Howto that comments should be added  to the question (as also indicated by  the comment made to the question)

Comment: @Howto and BTW `y.n(z)` should never return 7 or 4 - `y` is neither `B` nor `C`; it is an instance of `D`, which extends just `A`. it is not extending `B` nor `C` (as the name may [wrongly] suggest)